# Why does MonoDevelop always rebuild all projects in my C# solution?

Tags: mono, monodevelop, xbuild

I have a solution with 20 or so C# projects. The problem is that MonoDevelop always rebuilds all projects. This happens even when just one project changes that no other project depends on.

Note: I'm building using the "experimental" MSBuild/XBuild setting. This is required for cross-platform portability.

Versions:

- MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2.
- Mono 2.10.9
- Mac OS 10.7.3

Comment: If there's a bug with XBuild in Mono, it's probably much better to submit a bug report with them and provide a small, self-contained example of the problem.

Comment: @Robert: I don't know what the problem is yet. Also IMO stackoverflow is a much better place for others to discover such issues.

Comment: Yeah, SO is a much better place to discuss an issue and determine if it's a bug with XBuild or not. I was trying to say that when you figure it out, you should submit a bug report if it happens to be a XBuild bug.